# does Swift array.count get evaluated each time in a loop

Tags: swift

I suppose this is a question that must get asked for every language, but when you write for example:

```
while i < array.count {
    ...
}
```

does `array.count` get evaluated each time the loop runs? Is it better to store it in a `let` constant before running the loop like this?

```
let length = array.count
while i < length {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Usually such an explicit check can be *avoided* completely, e.g. `for idx in array.indices` or `for elem in array`. – Even `for i in 0..<array.count` would evaluate the count only once.

Comment: You better hope that `array.count` is evaluated each time because you just might be adding and/or removing objects from the array inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @rmaddy some compilers might detect this and change the behavior accordingly

Comment: "Yes" in a `while` and "no" in a `for` loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`while` loops (and `do while` loops) have their predicates evaluated on each iteration.

`for` loops evaluate the sequences once.

Here's is a demonstration:

```
var array: [Int]

print("Test Case 1 - while i < array.count")
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var i = 0
while i < array.count {
    print(array[i])
    if i < 3 { array.append(123) }
    i += 1
}
print("\r\nTest Case 2 - for i in array.indices")
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in array.indices {
    print(array[i])
    if i < 3 { array.append(123) }
}

print("\r\nTest Case 3 - for i in 0 ..< array.count")
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in 0 ..< array.count {
    print(array[i])
    if i < 3 { array.append(123) }
}
```

- `Test Case 1 - while i < array.count`

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  123
  123
  123
  ```
- `Test Case 2 - for i in array.indices`

  ```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
  ```
- `Test Case 3 - for i in 0 ..< array.count`

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  ```

#### Further details

`for` loops are just syntactic sugar for easily creating an iterator and iterating over it.

This `for` loop:

```swift
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for element in myArray {
    print(element)
}
```

behaves as if you wrote:

```swift
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let _myArrayIterator = myArray.makeIterator()

while let element = _myArrayIterator.next() {
    print(element)
}
```

The specific kind of iterator being made depends on the sequence being iterated. In the case of `Array`, it uses an `IndexingIterator` ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/efe762de0b9672e245ff6c00e063ff83f7641bc0/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift)). The default behaviour of `Collections` that use `IndexingIterator`s is to construct those iterators with a *copy* of `self` ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/efe762de0b9672e245ff6c00e063ff83f7641bc0/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1001)). When this happens, any further changes to `self` aren't reflecting in the iterator. It holds onto its own independent copy, so any changes to the size of your array aren't reflected in its independent copy.

You can try this for yourself, by making your own Sequence and Iterator which logs what's happening:

```swift
/// A simple wrapper around an array, which prints what's happening
struct ArrayWrapper<Element> {
    var elements: [Element]
}

extension ArrayWrapper: Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> MyIndexingIterator<Self> {
        print("ArrayWrapper.makeIterator() - The `for` loop made an iterator, copying the wrapped array\n")
        return MyIndexingIterator(
            elements: self, // A *copy* of `self` is given to the new iterator
            position: self.startIndex
        )
    }
}

extension ArrayWrapper: Collection { // Forward all the collection requirements to the real underlying array
    var startIndex: Int { elements.startIndex } 
    var endIndex: Int { elements.endIndex }
    func index(after i: Int) -> Int { elements.index(after: i) }
    
    subscript(index: Int) -> Element {
        get { elements[index] }
        set { elements[index] = newValue }
    }
}

struct MyIndexingIterator<Elements: Collection>: IteratorProtocol {
    let elements: Elements
    var position: Elements.Index
    
    mutating func next() -> Elements.Element? {
        print("ArrayWrapper.next() - The `for` loop is pulling the next element from the iterator")
        if position == elements.endIndex {
            print("\t- Position (\(position)) reached the endIndex (\(elements.endIndex)), so there are no more elements.")
            return nil
        }
        
        let element = elements[position]
        print("\t- Found \"\(element)\" at position \(position)")
        
        let positionBefore = position
        elements.formIndex(after: &position) // Advance the position by one
        print("\t- Advancing the position from \(positionBefore) -> \(position)")
        
        return element
    }
}

let myArray = ArrayWrapper(elements: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])

print("Before the `for` loop\n")
for element in myArray {
    print("`for` loop body - printing \"\(element)\"\n")
}
print("\nAfter the `for` loop")
```

prints:

```
Before the `for` loop

ArrayWrapper.makeIterator() - The `for` loop made an iterator, copying the wrapped array

ArrayWrapper.next() - The `for` loop is pulling the next element from the iterator
    - Found "A" at position 0
    - Advancing the position from 0 -> 1
`for` loop body - printing "A"

ArrayWrapper.next() - The `for` loop is pulling the next element from the iterator
    - Found "B" at position 1
    - Advancing the position from 1 -> 2
`for` loop body - printing "B"

ArrayWrapper.next() - The `for` loop is pulling the next element from the iterator
    - Found "C" at position 2
    - Advancing the position from 2 -> 3
`for` loop body - printing "C"

ArrayWrapper.next() - The `for` loop is pulling the next element from the iterator
    - Found "D" at position 3
    - Advancing the position from 3 -> 4
`for` loop body - printing "D"

ArrayWrapper.next() - The `for` loop is pulling the next element from the iterator
    - Found "E" at position 4
    - Advancing the position from 4 -> 5
`for` loop body - printing "E"

ArrayWrapper.next() - The `for` loop is pulling the next element from the iterator
    - Position (5) reached the endIndex (5), so there are no more elements.

After the `for` loop
```

Comment: does this mean unless you know what you're doing, you shouldn't add/remove elements in a for loop?

Comment: 99% of the time, there are better ways. Some times there aren't. But filter, slicing, etc. can get you pretty far.

Comment: If I tell you I understand why those `if statements` aren't executing, I'm lying

Comment: @Fourth Wanna elaborate on what's confusing you? I can probably help explain it

Comment: I just don't understand why the `append()` in cases 2 and 3 don't execute. Is it some safety feature from Swift because it's not re-evaluating the count on every iteration?

Comment: @Fourth It's not necessarily a safety thing, but it's just the semantics of `for`. It creates an iterator once at the start by calling `makeIterator` on the sequence you gave it. That iterator is already made; further changes to the array's count don't magically travel back in time to effect that iterator

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the value is accessed every time the condition is evaluated for the loop. In the example from the question, there would be no difference from moving it out to a variable because of how `Array` is implemented.

`Array` gets the `count` property because it conforms to `Collection`. The documentation for `count` in `Collection` states

> Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to RandomAccessCollection; otherwise, O(n), where n is the length of the collection.

- [Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/3017670-count)

Since `Array` also conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`, it is a constant time operation to get the count of the array. There shouldn't be any major performance difference between getting it once at the start vs every loop iteration.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question of *"does array.count get evaluated each time the loop runs"*.

Comment: To be clear, in `for i in 0 ..< A.count { ... }` , the `A.count` is evaluated exactly once.

Comment: Even though this answer doesn't answer the actual question. I was searching for exactly this information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's evaluated on each iteration.

Assigning to a constant will be slightly more performant. However with all of the optimisations in a modern compiler I wouldn't bother. Unless the loop count is going to be humongous.

Comment: Careful with a for loop ... `count` in a range will get evaluated only once!

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, it gets called every time

Let's run a simple test, first of all we need the following Array Extension

```
extension Array {
    var myCustomCount: Int {
        print("myCustomCount")
        return self.count
    }
}
```

And then we can try this code

```
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var i = 0
while i < nums.myCustomCount {
    i += 1
}
```

The output is

```
myCustomCount
myCustomCount
myCustomCount
myCustomCount
myCustomCount
myCustomCount
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Careful with for loops like the following. Since `elems.count` is part of a range that gets constructed once at the top of the loop, it is evaluated exactly once. The following code will die when `i = 4`:

```
var elems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in 0 ..< elems.count {
    if i % 2 == 0 { // remove even elements
        elems.remove(at: i)
    }
}
```

The `array.count` in your `while` does indeed get evaluated each time the condition is evaluated.